# Rider does not refresh MSBuild solution when CMake is run externally

Tags: c++, cmake, rider

My team is using CMake to generate MSBuild solutions for our C++ project. When we modify the CMake build and regenerate the solution files, VisualStudio automatically detects the changes and offers to reload. However, with JetBrains Rider, the solution is not reloaded, and we must delete the build directory to run the entire CMake generation step over again.

This is slowing down iteration times with Rider, is there a way to forcibly refresh the MSBuild solution from inside Rider?

We have tried using Rider's 'Invalidate Caches', but it has not helped the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you should use Rider, not CLion? You might also use Rider bug tracker to connect to the developers, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER

Comment: We prefer Rider because we also do a lot of work on Unreal Engine. Rider has been great for all of our C++ work so far, it'd be a shame to use another IDE over such a small, hopefully easy to fix issue